# Drag and drop UILabel from one view to another view - iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, drag-and-drop, uilabel, uitouch

I'm struggling with dragging and dropping an `UILabel` from one `UIView` to another `UIView`. Please check the code below:

```
  CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
  UIControl *control = sender;
  control.center = point;
```

Using this code I am not able to drag properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subview can't jump out of its subiewView and move into other View by itself.

What you have to do is in `touchesBegan` remove the label from its parentView. add anotherLabel exactly at the same position but in view which is superview of both the views (to be dragged from and to be dropped in).

Now in `touchesMoved`. move it based on touch position.

And in `touchesEnd`. find the position and loop over your views and find which view user dragged it to and add a new label as a subview in it on that position.

Update basic code (fix any syntax error if there are )

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   //get position
   // get label on that position
   [label removeFromSuperView];
   newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; //make newLabel iVar
   newLabel.textColor = label.textColor ; // etc copy values
   [self.view addSubView:newLabel]; //positioned at label
}

touchesMoved {
   //getPosition
   newLabel.position = position;
}

touchesEnded {
   //getPosition.
   self.view.subviews; // loop and find which view has the position.

   UILabel *finalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   finalLabel.center = newLabel.center;

   [newLabel removeFromSuperView];

   [ViewToBeDropped addSubview:finalLabel];
}
```

Comment: So without views,is it possible to do within the viewcontroller ?

Comment: Okay,but the thing is dragging should be visible to the user,so hide and placing it again won't works.Any idea ?

Comment: i mean just simply move one label within a viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for the help.It would be much helpful,if you share some codes.